# Using beforeEach to insert dummy data

Tags: mocha.js, supertest

When I use `beforeEach()` to insert dummy data to the DB, I get this error:

> Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

When I remove the `beforeEach()` call and try any test case, it works.  So can anyone show how to use `beforeEach()` correctly?

Here is my data:

```js
let dummyData = [{
    username: "ali",
    pasword: "ali",
    email: "ali@gmail.com"
}, {
    username: "joe",
    pasword: "joe",
    email: "joe@gmail.com"
}
]
```

Here is my `beforeEach` call:

```js
beforeEach(async function (done) {
    try {
        let result = await User.remove({});
        User.insertMany(dummyData);
    } catch (err) {
        return done(err)
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not called `done()` in your `beforeEach()`.

In your code, `done()` is called only if there is an error, but you need to call in the try too. If the code never reach the `catch` block, the `done()` is never called.

By the way, `done()` is not neccesary, so you can also not use. So you have two options:

1: Call `done()` after `insertMany()`:

```js
beforeEach(async function (done) {
    try {
        let result = await User.remove({});
        User.insertMany(dummyData);
        done() // <-- This line
    } catch (err) {
        return done(err)
    }
})
```

2: Not call `done()` (and the test will not fail if the `await` execution pass 2000ms):

```js
beforeEach(async function () {
    try {
        let result = await User.remove({});
        User.insertMany(dummyData);
    } catch (err) {
        // do whatever you want
    }
})
```

But I suposse you want to use `done()` to ensure the result is correct, so the first option fits better with your code I think.